# How to access working instance of different component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, instance

We are developing a project that displays camera streams via players. We can add or delete camera info from db and according to that page of component displays players.

Our problem is that, in ngOnInit() part it subscribes web service and gets camera records and creates players.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    videojs.options.flash.swf = '../video-js.swf';

    // videojs("streamPlayer").ready(function(){     
    //     var myPlayer:Player = this;
    //   });

    this.restervice.getCamList()

      .then(
      streams => {


        this.zone.run(() => {

          this.cameras = streams;



          if (streams.length != 0)
            console.log('result: ' + this.cameras[0].rtspUrl);




          setTimeout(() => {

            for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.cameras.length; this.i++) {
              console.log("Camera " + ((this.i) + 1) + " :" + this.cameras[this.i].name);

              this.videoJSplayer = videojs(this.cameras[this.i].name, {


                responsive: true, width: 600, height: 400,
                techOrder: ['flash'],

                sources: [{
                  src: 'rtmp://' + this.serverAddr + '/IPCamera/' + this.cameras[this.i].name,
                  type: 'rtmp/flv',
                  label: 'Flash'
                }],
                flash: {
                  swf: '../video-js.swf'
                }
              });
            }
          }, 500);
        });

      },

      error => {
        console.log('!!!Error!!! ' + error);
      },


    );

  }
```

Another components add new camera record to db and we want to refresh dom elements of displaying page players in other words creates new player or remove by refreshing to component not whole page.

If we call refreshDom() function

```
  refreshDom():void {
    this.ngOnDestroy();
    this.ngOnInit();
  }
```

from its own component, it successfully refresh dom elements(removes and adds) but if we call it from other component which we perform db operations, it take instance of component but it can not perform operations because we can not take working instance of it probably it creates another instance.

```
  this.restervice.addCameraInfo(this.cam).subscribe(
  streams => {
    console.log('result!!!: ' + streams.success);
    if(streams.success==true){

    this.dialogRef.close(Camera);
    this.verify=true;
    this.playlive.refreshDom();            
    }
```

We tried classic instance creation, taking ComponentRef or nGzone solutions but they dont work?

Comment: Your code snippets are not fully indented and hard to read. I think you need to show more code in your last example: how do you get a reference on playlive?
What is the resulting behavior? Do you have an error in your browser console?

Comment: @Melou I edited indentations sorry :( we get PlayLiveComponent instance in constructor as "public playlive: PlayLiveComponent" also put "providers: [PlayLiveComponent]"  As a result we can not reach active instance of component, for example active component get info from web service on it ngOninit part but we can not reach them etc.